Azure Web App failing to deploy with Windows Containers
I'm trying to deploy a windows container that holds a simple ASP.NET Core Web App to an azure web app. I've created a container registry, and pushed my docker image to it. However, every time I try to create a web app that uses the docker image, it fails to deploy with


I'm absolutely certain it's not an issue with my docker image. I've deployed it from visual studio, visual studio code, and the command line. All of my files are the standard inputs from creating a ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages) project in visual stuido. Here are my settings for the [web app settings]

when I'm creating the [app service plan]

and when I'm configuring the [azure container registry]

I'm really not sure what the issue could be anymore. I've tried switching pricing plans, locations, recreating the project from the group up, deploying new resources. I tried a container app but that failed because I'm using docker-windows images no Linux. Azure says windows containers are supported but at this point I'm not sure.
I'm new to docker an have only been working with azure for a couple months so it's possible I missed some crucial step somewhere, but I've been following simple documentation and it's still failing.
I'm really stumped here, if anyone could offer any guidance that would be great.
EDIT:
I tried creating a new resource group, same format didn't change anything with the error. The only thing in the resource group is the ACR and the web app, the resource group is located in East US. Swithcing pricing plans for the web app gave me a new error however:
(Code: ValidationForResourceFailed)
This region has quota of 0 PremiumMV3 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU. (Code: SubscriptionIsOverQuotaForSku)

The monthly cost for this app would be over my student-subscription-credit-limit, but I wouldn't have it up that long as this is a demo app. It might be a limit of the student subscription, also with the IT crisis happening this could just be a byproduct, although this issue has persisted sience wednesday 7/17/2024
Here is my dockerfile as requested:
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["container-app.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./container-app.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./container-app.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./container-app.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "container-app.dll"]`


provide error in text format.

Share your docker file.

In our Enterprise subscription, we can only see the pricing tiers for these 11 options.  It is not clear whether Azure has other options for student subscriptions. It is recommended to upgrade to the highest pricing tier of the available options before trying again.

In addition, if there is already a Linux appservice plan in this resourcegroup, it is not supported to continue to create Windows-related resources in the Free tier, so please check.

@Cameron Cox Try to Create new resource Group. The Error you are facing is related to resource group.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I've updated the post, new information is provided under the EDIT: section

I created a simple ASP .NET Core application and deployed it to Azure App Service (Windows) Via Azure Container registry.
The error message you're encountering says Windows containers are not allowed in the resource group. Try creating a new resource group and deploying the app again.

Right click on your project in solution explorer => Add => Docker support => Make sure you select Target OS as windows.



I successfully pushed the image to container registry.

Right click on your project in solution explorer=>publish=>Azure => Azure container registry =>select your registry => Finish.






When creating the Azure Web App, choose the "Container" publish option.

Make sure the App Service is set to use the correct container image from your Azure Container Registry (ACR).




Here's the output Deployment:


In the end, I determined that it must be a limitation of my subscription or Azure web apps that use Windows containers that were causing the error.
I switched to Linux containers and followed the steps listed in @Sirra Sneha's answer and that worked to deploy my web app.
I'm still not sure which it is, as I can't find any documentation that says I'm unable to deploy Windows container web apps through a student subscription. I also couldn't create premium web apps (also likely due to my subscription) so if you're struggling to deploy Windows containers maybe try using a premium app service plan instead of a free tier.
